# What does the struct fact_entry *fact_table; mean?

Tags: c, loops, data-structures, command-line, factorial

I have the task to complete a code that print the factorial of a number from an input from the command line. I am trying to understand the code but I am new to C programming and structures, so I am not sure what does struct fact_entry *fact_table; does  and also I dont know how to programm fact_table in order to access the variable with the line:

```
printf ("%d %lld %s\n", 
    fact_table[i].n, fact_table[i].lli_fact, fact_table[i].str_fact);}
```

Could you help me?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LIMIT 20

struct fact_entry
{                               /* Definition of each table entry */
  int n;
  long long int lli_fact;       /* 64-bit integer */
  char *str_fact;
};

void
panic (char *m)
{
  fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", m);
  exit (0);
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n;
  int i;
  struct fact_entry *fact_table;

  if (argc != 2)
    panic ("wrong parameters");

  n = atoi (argv[1]);
  if (n < 0)
    panic ("n too small");
  if (n > LIMIT)
    panic ("n too big");

/* Your code starts here */
  // Allocate memory
  // Compute fact(n) for i=0 to n

  

/* Your code ends here */

  // print computed numbers
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
      printf ("%d %lld %s\n", fact_table[i].n, fact_table[i].lli_fact,
              fact_table[i].str_fact);
    }

/* Your code starts here */
  // Free memory

  

/* Your code ends here */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This struct fact_entry *fact_table; is a declaration of a pointer. Your question should be closed because you need at first to read a book on C for beginners,

Comment: Here is a hint to get you started in the "Allocate memory" section: `fact_table = calloc(n, sizeof(struct fact_entry));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question can be best answered when focusing on what structs are. In your case, you can see that a struct is being defined as

```
struct fact_entry
{                               /* Definition of each table entry */
  int n;
  long long int lli_fact;       /* 64-bit integer */
  char *str_fact;
};
```

You can think of a struct as a group of data. In this case the data consists of an integer, called `n`, a long long int, called `lli_fact`, and a character pointer, called `str_fact`. You can define a new struct either directly or as a pointer. However, when you define a struct as a pointer you have to `calloc()`, meaning 'free', the memory for that struct (otherwise you will get a `segmentation fault`).
This means, either:

```
 struct fact_entry fact_table;
```

Or, as a pointer/array:

```
 struct fact_entry *fact_table;
```

However, like I said, to not get a `segmentation fault` in the latter, you need to allocate the memory. From the definition you know that the memory needed for one struct is going to be `sizeof(struct fact_entry)`. Then:

```
fact_table = calloc(n, sizeof(struct fact_entry));
```

This will allocate memory for `n` structs. Now, you can access each field of the struct with:

```
fact_table[i].n = someVal1;
fact_table[i].lli_fact = someVal2;
fact_table[i].str_fact = somePointerToCharacterArray;
```

Later, the content can be printed with:

```
printf ("%d %lld %s\n", fact_table[i].n, fact_table[i].lli_fact,
          fact_table[i].str_fact);
```

However, this was just a quick rundown of what structs are and how they work. I didn't cover any specifics and didn't include all the detail. For more about this topic you could read some more [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm).